# How to give padding dynamically to image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have svg box, inside svg box have image, i want give padding left and right to image dynamically,how do i do that using javasscript? 
I have can give width and height as:

```
img.style.width = img.clientWidth + 100 + 'px';
```

But i m unable to do for padding or margin.I have tried using `style.paddingLeft` and `style.marginLeft` it wont work,Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are doing and it not working?

Comment: I m annoting the image as rectangle boxes, as my mouse moves outside image div,image should move.but is not moving @Shahzad

Comment: can you add the code @Student001 of your HTML, JavaScript, CSS etc? It will help more.

Comment: its huge, how do i do that ?

Comment: just give partials of html and css that connect to the question.

Comment: SVG doesn't have any padding. What you can do is nest your image inside a `div` and assign padding to it.